# NeDB How can i use variable in find query?

Tags: find, nedb

how can i use variable in my find query, something like this:

db have docs like

```
{choices:{'04-09-2017':'a'},b:'b'},
{choices:{'04-10-2017':'a'},c:'c'}
```

my query is

```
 var x = "choices.04-09-2017"
 db.find({
        x: {
            $exists: true
        }
    }, function(err, docs) {

    });
```

How i can define that x is a variable not is a property?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easier if you define an object that represent your search:

```
var toFind = {};
var firstTerm = "choices";
var secondTerm = "04-09-2017";
toFind[firstTerm]={};
toFind[firstTerm][secondTerm] = {$exists = true};

db.find(toFind, function(err, docs) {
  // put here your callback
});
```

this should work.

in your example x in

```
{
  x: {
    $exists: true
  }
}
```

is treated as the key of the obj searched and is not evaluated.